# Setup network between 2 computers connected using wifi

Tags: networking, sql-server, wifi, network-share, sql-server-2008-r2

In my office I have a WiFi Router that allows 2 computers to connect to Internet. I have 2 questions -

1. How can I create a network between these 2 computers for file sharing?
2. Can I access SQL server installed on 1 computer from 2nd computer? If yes, how?

**EDIT**
I am a newbie here and I really dont know if I am violating any rules, if yes, please comment an I will fix/update my question.

Comment: Please place your comment for downvote, so that I can edit & modify my question.

Comment: You're getting downvotes because this is a site for professional network engineers to discuss problems they experience in professional system administration. Questions like "how can I connect two computers together" belong on different sites.

Comment: OK, I have flagged my question to be closed.

Answer (score 3):

> How can I create a network between these 2 computers for file sharing?

Connect them both to the same router at the same time.

> Can I access SQL server installed on 1 computer from 2nd computer? If yes, how?

Yes. There's nothing special you need to do. Whatever tool you are using should let you specify the server you want to connect to. Specify the name of the other computer.